# Generic constrained type default value

Tags: swift

Consider the following code:

```
protocol JSONParserType {
    associatedtype Element
}

// MARK: - Entities
struct Item {}

// MARK: - Parsers
struct OuterParser<T: JSONParserType where T.Element == Item>: JSONParserType {
    typealias Element = Item
    let innerParser: T

    init(innerParser: T = InnerParser()) {
        self.innerParser = innerParser
    }
}

struct InnerParser: JSONParserType {
    typealias Element = Item
}
```

The `OuterParser` has a child parser that should be constrained to a specific type. Unfortunately providing a default value in the initializer (or in the property definition itself) does lead to the compiler throwing a "Default argument value of type 'InnerParser' cannot be converted to type 'T'".

If I remove the default value assignment and just instantiate the `OuterParser` providing the `InnerParser` explicitly, everything is fine.

```
let outerParser = OuterParser(innerParser: InnerParser())
```

My question is what's the reason that the approach providing a default value that actually meets the constraints does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *actual* type of `T` isn't defined by the class – it's defined by the code that uses the class. It will therefore be defined before you do anything in your class (at either instance or static level). You therefore can't assign `InnerParser` to `T`, as `T` has already been defined to be a given type by that point, which may well not be `InnerParser`.

For example, let's consider that you have another parser struct:

```
struct AnotherParser: JSONParserType {
    typealias Element = Item
}
```

and let's assume that your current code compiles. Now consider what would happen when you do this:

```
let parser = OuterParser<AnotherParser>()
```

You've defined the generic type to be `AnotherParser` – but the initialiser will try to assign `InnerParser` to your property (now of type `AnotherParser`). These types don't match, therefore it cannot possibly work.

Following the same logic, this implementation also won't work:

```
struct OuterParser<T: JSONParserType where T.Element == Item>: JSONParserType {
    typealias Element = Item
    let innerParser: T

    init() {
        self.innerParser = InnerParser()
    }

    init(innerParser: T) {
        self.innerParser = innerParser
    }
}
```

As there's no guarantee that the generic type `T` will be the same type as `InnerParser`. Sure, you can force downcast to `T` – but that'll just make you code crash if the types aren't compatible.

Unfortunately, there's no real clean solution to this problem. I think the best your best option is probably to create two factory methods for creating your `OuterParser` instance.

```
enum Parser {
    static func createParser() -> OuterParser<InnerParser> {
        return OuterParser(innerParser:InnerParser())
    }
    static func createParser<T>(innerParser:T) -> OuterParser<T> {
        return OuterParser(innerParser:innerParser)
    }
}
```

```
let innerParser = Parser.createParser() // OuterParser<InnerParser>

let anotherParser = Parser.createParser(AnotherParser()) // OuterParser<AnotherParser>
```

We're using an caseless enum here to avoid polluting the global namespace with extra functions.

Although this isn't very Swifty, and for that reason I would also recommend maybe rethinking your logic for how you define your parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was a tricky one, for me at least.

Comment: @mAu Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

type `T` more like a `child protocol` of `JSONParserType` you can convert it:

```
init(innerParser: T = InnerParser() as! T) {
    self.innerParser = innerParser
}
```